# Oracle APEX - text field displays a dash

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I have a text field on my page which has its source as a database column. Whenever the field is null, the dash is displayed. How can I prevent it from displaying a dash?
Unlike in a report, there is no `Show Null Values As` option for a standalone text field...

is clearning it on page load my only option?

Answer (score 0):

retrieve your data by means of source of the type of article = column database

Comment: not sure what you mean... I am already retrieving it as a database column. Could you please explain?